# C# transparent border for borderless form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I'm creating a borderless form and I want to add a custom border to it. When I add the background for the form however, it doesn't show well, and it is not transparent.

This is what I want to use as my border.:
[image: Screenshot]

When I set the Form's transparency for White the shadow disappears, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: WinForms. I assume it would be eaiser to do in WPF?

Comment: May have better luck using a color like [Fuchsia](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fuchsia.aspx) for the transparent color (and is more commonly practiced).

Comment: This makes no sense, how could a transparent window cast a shadow?  Don't set the TransparencyKey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I cheated a bit but what I did was simply overriding the CreateParams to draw dropshadow even though it's a borderless window. It does exactly what I wanted so I went with it.
 Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to use a semi-transparent (alpha) image as the form background in WinForms, as described in this article: [A lovely goldfish desktop pet (using alpha-PNG and GDI+)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/LovelyGoldFishDeskPet.aspx).

It uses native interop to blend the image with the desktop.

Also, check out [UpdateLayeredWindow function (User32.dll)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.updatelayeredwindow) on [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/index.aspx). There is also an example how to use it.

**[Edit]**

There is also a link on pinvoke.net to [Mike Swanson's blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mswanson/archive/2005/07/07/436618.aspx) about the same subject. It uses the same code as described in mentioned links, but it's a VS project which does exactly what OP wants: a splash form with a semitransparent PNG image as a background.

Comment: Using UpdateLayeredWindow() is only a difficult way to use the Opacity and TransparencyKey properties.

Comment: @Hans: `TransparencyKey` only defines a single color to be considered transparent, similar to the way GIF images support transparency. What OP wants to achieve is full support for the alpha channel, allowing fine opacity gradients in PNG files.