# Window form shaped corners

Tags: winforms

Im trying to create a borderless forms (.net 2 winforms) with smooth rounded corners. nothing works anti alias, API, different image formats and transparency. rounded corners will not look smooth.

does anyone have any suggestions?
thank you

I have found a solution @

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/SemiTranDlgWithCtrls.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question might yield some answers:

[C# transparent border for borderless form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873157/c-transparent-border-for-borderless-form)

Off-hand I know that WinForms and transparency are not the best of friends.